# Counting the number of rows that has repeated elements in the columns

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Suppose the following list:
$$
\begin{matrix}
j_1 & j_2 & j_3 & j_4\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
  & \vdots  &   \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3
\end{matrix}
$$
In this list, lets group repeated entries in the columns such that:
$$
\begin{matrix}
j_1 & j_2 & j_3 & j_4\\
\{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \}\\
\{1 & 1 & 1\} & \{2\} \\
\{1 & 1 & 1\} & \{3\} \\
  & \vdots  &   \\
\{2 & 2 & 2 & 2\} \\
  & \vdots  &   \\
\{3\} & \{1 & 1 & 1\} \\
\{3 & 3\} & \{2 & 2\} \\
  & \vdots  &   \\
\{3 & 3 & 3 & 3\}
\end{matrix}
$$

Is there a way to calculate how many entries the subgroups are equal to a certain number? Notice that the subgroup $\{ j_1 j_2 j_3 j_4 \}$ counts 3. On the other hand, it is not that obvious to calculate for the other groups.

Is there a generalized way to calculate this if I have $j_1, j_2, \dots, j_n $ ?

Comment: So you mean that there are two elements equal and one different? The answer of that is choosing the indices in $\binom{3}{2}$ and choosing the number, you have $3$ ways and choosing the other number in $2$ ways so $\binom{3}{2}\cdot 3\cdot 2=18$ Now what do you mean by generalized? How many repeated you want?

Comment: The number of rows without repetitions are permutations of 1,2,3, i.e. 3!=6. From here you can find the number of rows with at least two repeated elements.

Comment: Generalization means that I want to choose the size of the column and count the rows where numbers repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It helped a lot!

Comment: @CláudioFerreiraDias is the generalization in my answer not the one you were seeking?......the size of the columns in dependent on the value of $k$

Comment: Oh. Sorry.. Thanks for your feedback. I am writing a comment in your post. I just need a couple of minutes.

Comment: So is the number fixed or why is there no something like $\{4\,4\,4\,4\}$?

Comment: { 4 4 4 4 } is a subset of repeated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering directly for the generalised case:

Let's denote the arrangement as:

$$\_ \ \_ \ \_ \ .....(n \ times)$$

So let's say that each $\_$ is can be filled with $k$ options. ($k=3$ in the example in the question)

Now if we need to calculate for $r$ repetitions of a option from the $k$ options, ($r=2$ in the example in the question)

First choose an option from $k$ : $\binom{k}{1}$ ways

and then choose $r$ places to place this option: $\binom{n}{r}$

Now look at the other $n-r$ places left, where you can place different characters from $k-1$ options : $\binom{k-1}{n-r} (n-r)!$ ways.

So the total ways:

$$\binom{k}{1}\binom{n}{r}\binom{k-1}{n-r}(n-r)!$$

(Place respective bounds on r,k)

So for your example in the question:

$n=3$, we have total of 3 options: 1, 2, 3 ($k=3$)

So for 3 repetitions, ($r=3$)

$$=\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{0}(0!)=3$$

For 2 repetitions ($r=2$)

$$=\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}(1)!=18$$

Hope that helped...... :-)

Comment: I started to test your solution and it was on the right track. The problem is that I oversimplified the problem. I want to take the elements of the columns and give rise to a partition. This way if I have a row [ 1 2 1 2 ] or [ 1 1 2 2 ] I give rise to the partition { {j1, j3},{j2,j4}} or  { {j1, j2},{j3, j4}}, respectively. Thus, I am actually interested in counting partitions. In the end, I want to know how many rows give rise to partitions with cardinality 2, 3, and so on...

Comment: I will fix the question to the new context...